# CakePHP - How to retrieve data from another model in controller

Tags: php, cakephp

Currently i have 2 models. Users and Appbreak.
They have associations of
Users has many appbreak.
Appbreaks belongs to users
In my appbreak controller, there is a approve function which is called when a button from the view page is pressed.

In this function, i will need to update a value in the table of appbreak and a value in users table.
I'm able to update value in appbreak by using the following:

```
$this->Appbreak->id = $id;
    $this->Appbreak->set('approve', 'Yes');
    $this->Appbreak->save();
```

However, i'm unable to pull the required data value from users table. <-- need to do so as i need to do some calculations before passing back the calculated value.

Am i able to get data from another model using the request method? Or do i need to use the find method? If i use the find method, am i able to update the the values and save it back into the database?

Comment: Do not forget to upvote the right answer :)

Comment: Do not have enough reputation to vote up..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use find() to get your values, and if you need to update the values, use save(). Like so:

```
$this->Appbreak->Users->find('first', $params);
```

(as described [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html))

To save, simply create an array with **at least** the relevant record id. Include any fields you want to update, and then  call the save method on the array like so:

```
$data = array('id' => 10, 'title' => 'My new title');
// This will update Recipe with id 10
$this->Recipe->save($data);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use any number of models in a controller .
Declare the 'uses' array in controller

```
<?php
class DemoController extends AppController{
    public $uses=array('Appbreak','User');
}
?>
```

To get data from `AppBreak` model use find method of
`$this->AppBreak` object
Similarly to get data for `User` use find method of
`$this->User` object

Comment: i get it... so we still have to use the find method to get the datas... i was thinking whether we can use the request method to get the datas?